# OEM for using Elastic stack basic subscription

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am using Basic subscription of elastic and planning to deploy the same on customer tools with basic license. Should I become an **OEM** partner with elastic if I have to deploy or distribute elastic components with basic license?

Also what is the difference between the **OpenSource** and **Basic** subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

The Basic subscription is based on the elastic distro containing non open source features. So if you want to distribute features covered by the basic subscription you need to check the OEM partnership.

Comment: Just adding on top of that: Bunding the Basic licensed products is currently being done by some projects, but please discuss it with the OEM team first.